# Constructor value is not accessible in function

Tags: javascript, oop

Here I have a very simple class and I have a constructor inside of it and in constructor I am declaring a value **donut_count** but when I try to access that value in another function it says undefined why it is undefined:

```
class DonutMaker {
  constructor() {
    var donut_count = 1;
    this.target = document.getElementById("donut_creater");
    this.target.addEventListener("click", this.donutCreate);
  }
  donutCreate() {
    console.log(this.donut_count);
  }
}

let obj1 = new DonutMaker();
```

Comment: `this.donutCreate` should be `() => this.donutCreate()`

Comment: is there a canonical dupe for this?

Comment: @gog - Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback I often add [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) as well, for broader context.